# CK editor edit page is not showing youtube embaded code

Tags: cakephp, ckeditor

I have added CK editor in my cakePHP website. It is working fine for adding and editing normal text. It is also working while adding youtube embaded video. But when try to edit this added youtube embaded content it is showing blank editor. I can see by doing echo that embaded code is available.

This is how I have added ck editor in add and edit page. This is the cakePHP structure

```
<?php
    echo $this->Ck->input(
    __('policy'), [
               'label' => [
                'class' => 'control-label',
                'text' => __('Policy *')
               ],
             'class' => 'form-control'                                            
            ]);
   ?>
```

Comment: Looks like you're using some non-standard Ck plugin here. What's the source of that?

Comment: This is the library I am using https://github.com/CakeCoded/CkEditor